# Case insensitivity in GraphDB

Tags: sparql, graphdb

Is there a way to match without case sensitivity in GraphDB?
The test dataset is pretty small. Around 8m triples.

```
SELECT ?s ?name 

WHERE {
    
?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/simplename/name> ?name. 
?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/provider> "nhle".

OPTIONAL {?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/county/> "Essex"} 
OPTIONAL {?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/district/> "Epping Forest"} 
OPTIONAL {?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/parish/> "Buckhurst Hill"} 

}
```

I can, of course, use FILTER - but it takes a good seven seconds to return which is too slow.

```
SELECT ?s ?name ?county ?district ?parish

WHERE {

?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/simplename/name> ?name. 

?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/provider> "nhle".

OPTIONAL {?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/county/> ?county} 

OPTIONAL {?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/district/> ?district} 

OPTIONAL {?s <http://www.sample.org.uk/data/schema/parish/> ?parish} 



FILTER (lcase(?county)='essex'

&& lcase(?district)='epping forest'

&& lcase(?parish)='buckhurst hill'

  )

}
```

Comment: same as for the Jena thread, did you try to put the filters inside the `OPTIONAL` patterns? And also for GraphDB, there is a setup for fulltext index support which might scale better then a scan on all literals: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/9.8/free/general-full-text-search-with-connectors.html

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, sorry for that (I cannot make a comment).

Since you already know you want to match against *the county of Essex*, as apposed to *anything with the label "essex" or "Essex"*, it might be better to use the URI for that county, instead of a label. The URI could for instance be:

```
<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q23240>
```

At least this will prevent you from accidentally matching something completely different with the label "Essex", p.e. the Essex whale ship ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essex_(whaleship)))

Ofcourse I'm not aware of what your data looks like, so this may be of no use to you. Still worth pointing out hopefully.